# Python: input to os.system getting split

Tags: python, linux, list, os.system

I wish to pass a list of list as argument to my python program. When I am doing the same on normal shell it works absolutely fine however when I do the same from within os.system, it just splits my list of list

```
import sys
import json
import os
#path=~/Desktop/smc/fuzzy/
os.system("test -d results || mkdir results")
C1=[-5,-2.5,0,2.5,5];spr1=2.5;LR1=[10,20,30,30,30]
C2=[-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4];spr2=1;LR2=[30,40,50,50,50]
C3=[-4,-2,0,2,4];spr3=2;LR3=[40,50,60,60,60]
arg=[[spr1,LR1,C1],[spr2,LR2,C2],[spr3,LR3,C3]]
for i in range(len(arg)):
    print ('this is from the main automate file:',arg[i])
    print('this is stringized version of the input:',str(arg[i]))
    inp=str(arg[i])
    os.system("python "+"~/Desktop/smc/fuzzy/"+"name_of_my_python_file.py "+ inp)   
    os.system("mv "+"*_"+str(arg[i])+" results")
```

This is the error that it is throwing-

```
('this is from the main automate file:', [2.5, [10, 20, 30, 30, 30], [-5, -2.5, 0, 2.5, 5]])
('this is stringized version of the input:', '[2.5, [10, 20, 30, 30, 30], [-5, -2.5, 0, 2.5, 5]]')
('from the main executable file:', ['/home/amardeep/Desktop/smc/fuzzy/name_of_my_python_file.py', '[2.5,', '[10,', '20,', '30,', '30,', '30],', '[-5,', '-2.5,', '0,', '2.5,', '5]]'])
```

In the third line it is just splitting the list by commas and hence messing the list. Is there a way I can by pass this? 
Instead of passing a neat list of list like:

```
[2.5, [10, 20, 30, 30, 30], [-5, -2.5, 0, 2.5, 5]]
```

it is passing something like

```
[2.5,', '[10,', '20,', '30,', '30,', '30],', '[-5,', '-2.5,', '0,', '2.5,', '5]]']
```

I need to be able to pass a list of list as argument to my python program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. don't use `os.system`, it's deprecated and not able to compose a proper command line with quoted args, etc... (Since `inp` contains spaces, you need quoting, and it can become a mess quickly enough)
2. don't use `mv` when you have `shutil.move`

my proposal: use `subprocess.check_call` (python <3.5), using `os.path.expanduser` allows to evaluate `~` without needing `shell=True`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["python",
           os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/smc/fuzzy/name_of_my_python_file.py"),inp])
```

Passing arguments as a list of arguments allows to let `check_call` handle the quoting when needed.

Now, to move the files use a loop on globbed files and `shutil`:

```
import glob,shutil
for file in glob.glob("*_"+str(arg[i])):
   shutil.move(file,"results")
```

However, in the long run, since you're calling a python program from a python program and you're passing python lists, you'd be better off with simple module imports and function calls, passing the lists directly, not converted as string, where you have to parse them back in the subprocess.

This present answer is better suited for non-python subprocesses.

As an aside, don't use system calls to create directories:

```
os.system("test -d results || mkdir results")
```

can be replaced by full-python code, OS independent:

```
if not os.path.isdir("results"):
   os.mkdir("results")
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me try this! Also, will it read the list properly and not mess it up?

Comment: I think you could avoid creating a python system call. Just create functions and import them (see the end of my answer)

Comment: Thanks a ton Jean! Your help was really valuable! it saved me tones and tones of trouble! But now I am running into some other problem. I will probably open another thread for that. But thanks for this one.

Comment: Also there is a this thing, when I make the changes as you have suggested above,my code runs fine, however it is running sequentially and only one core is being utilized. I want to run it in such a manner that my python program is launched in 3 different cores with these individual arguments. Thanks a lot

Comment: don't open another thread. Just _create_ a python `thread` and run the `subprocess.check_call` from the thread.

Comment: Hi Jean, I am afraid I couldnt understand your last comment, can you tell me what changes do I need to do in my code so that  my main python program is launched in 3 different cores with those individual arguments independently?

Comment: lookup `threading` module or `multithreading` pool of processes. There's a lot of Q&A on this site about that. The documentation is also very good